# BigCommerce: Identify Logged-In User Role

Tags: roles, bigcommerce

I'm working on a Stencil site where the client would like to show Internal Notes to logged in staff.

My first idea is to check the staff role and show the info based on that but I can't seem to find that type of check in the BC docs anywhere.

My next idea is to base it off the email.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you edit your post to include more info? Do you mean the internal notes on the order level? And should this be visible to all logged in staff users, or just users with certain permission levels?

Comment: You can make customer groups and assign some particular roles to each customer groups, then fetch customer group name and implement any functionality related to that customer group name. I.E. Make a customer group named Staff and another one is all customer. fetch that name on any page using customer group name handlebars expression.

Comment: Thank you @BuggyParadox!!  That's what I needed to get this part going!

Answer (score 0):

You can make customer groups and assign some particular roles to each customer groups, then fetch customer group name and implement any functionality related to that customer group name. I.E. Make a customer group named Staff and another one is all customer. fetch that name on any page using customer group name handlebars expression.

And you're done...:D